# Aside from 'xinput' how does linux know to use a touchscreen on startup?

Tags: linux, xorg, xinput

I am trying to find a generic way for Linux to recognize my custom touchscreen driver without using xinput / xorg config. I'm not certain what Linux system the customer will be using, but I can be certain of a fixed com port such as ttyS0.

How does Linux recognize the touchscreen device and attach to the device ttyS0 if not using Xorg / xinput? Or do all Linux OS with a UI use Xorg?

Comment: To answer your last question, Xorg is  _not_ what all Linux installations use. There are alternatives available, with the most popular being [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/)

Comment: Sounds like a job for `inputattach`...

Comment: Stephen - Is it possible to add a custom driver to inputattach? I only saw the drivers that inputattach already came with. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can add a custom driver, as long as you have a matching line discipline in the kernel. The way it usually happens is that people send me a patch (or rather, `linuxconsole-dev@lists.sourceforge.net`) and I merge it and release a new version.

Comment: I can't unfortunately release it to the community as it's using a proprietary interface that we had to sign a NDA for. So would Xorg be the better option in this case?

Comment: It might be, if you can get it working with X.org on its own. I’m working on adding a generic interface to `inputattach`, which might work for you, but that won’t be ready this week ;-).

Comment: Awesome I'll try X.org for now and come back if it doesn't work for them. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Xorg did not work, but I modified inputattach.c and that worked. Make sure to run it as sudo or it will complain about setting the line discipline!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I added my device to the array of 'struct input_types' within inputattach.c. This source file I had to find online. After adding the correct parameters to this list and recompiling, I was then able to start my driver running my own built inputattach file: ./myInputAttach -mydriver /dev/ttyUSB0

Running a tail -f /var/log/kern.log shows "printk" output from the driver starting and the interrupts.

I still do not see the driver on xinput, but this at least solves the issue of the driver not being used.